# How to install powershell as a prerequisite?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, powershell, installation

I am using Visual Studio 2010 setup project

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you are allowed to redistribute PowerShell.  And at any rate, it is built in to Windows 7 and Server 2008 R2.  All the other platforms have separate installers as well.  I think it would be best to just notify your customers that they need PowerShell 2.0.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem in the StudioShell installer - wanted to make sure PoSh 2.0 is installed.  I did a cursory check for the executable with a minimum version number, and  added a launch condition that notified the user of the missing prerequisite and offered to open a web page to the PowerShell download.  Seemed like the most legally helpful approach.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way, albiet requiring you to build some MSI thing manually that will get it from MS and install it for you. I know the exchange install used that technique. You can also get a license/permission from MS to redistribute the official installers.